# Using *.cpp in cmake add_executable

Tags: c++, cmake

For example I have a lot of source files in src directory. How can I do something like `add_executable(ex src/*.cpp)`?

Comment: Google `cmake file glob`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using the [file manipulation command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html)

```
file(GLOB My_Source_Files src/*.cpp)
add_executable(ex ${My_Source_Files})
```